# Seaborn scatter plot help: plotting a dataset with an intuitive x axis

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I didn't exactly know how to phrase this question (so if you have a thought on better phrasing please comment) but I'll provide an example of the data type to explain what I have and what I am trying to plot. Right now I have a dataset I am trying to build a scatterplot with where the x-axis is a distance and the y axis is time.

The data set looks like:

```
start   end   time  group  
0       4     0.91   1  
2       12    0.98   1  
12      15    0.88   1
0       4     0.925  2
2       12    0.902  2
12      15    1.0    2  
....
```

I read the data set into pandas and made a scatter plot like so plotting time on the y axis and the starting distance point on the x axis. *Quick edit but I also want to set the hue/point style based on the "group" category*:

```
fig_dims = (24, 16) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=fig_dims)
sns.scatterplot(data=dfand looks like this,ax=ax, x= "start", y="time",hue="group",style="group",s=1) 
sns.set_style("white")
plt.show()
```

The problem I am running in to is plotting this same plot when the data gets more complex. Specifically this data set above is working off a continuous x axis scale from 0 to 15, but I have a similar data set where instead of working with continuous data I am working with data broken up by a marker category where the count resets to zero:

```
start   end time    group   marker
0   4   0.91    1   1
2   12  0.98    1   1
12  15  0.88    1   1
0   4   0.9252  1   1
2   12  0.9022  1   1
12  15  1   2   1
1   6   0.91    1   2
3   11  0.98    1   2
11  22  0.88    1   2
1   6   0.9252  2   2
3   11  0.9022  2   2
11  22  1   2   2
1   6   0.91    1   3
3   11  0.98    1   3
11  22  0.88    1   3
1   6   0.9252  2   3
3   11  0.9022  2   3
11  22  1   2   3
    ....
```

So in this example assume marker 1 is a length of 15 (0-15) and marker 2 is a length of 22 (0-22) and that the two markers do not overlap rather they are in succession so what I want to plot is a scatter plot that has the same y axis of time, but on the x axis iterates through the different markers and has in succession marker 1, marker 2, marker 3, etc.

My thought was I would input a order/length file that has the information about the marker id and the length of that marker like this:

```
marker start end
1      0     15
2      0     22
```

And then I would start iterating through the values in my data frame for marker 1 and once I hit the second marker I would create a new value that takes into account the distance from marker 1 so would end up plotting a final dataset that is modified to look like this where marker 2 has had 15 added to its start/end values to represent that its starting point is immediately following marker 1 rather than literal 0.

```
start   end   time  group  marker
0       4     0.91   1     1
2       12    0.98   1     1
12      15    0.88   1     1
0       4     0.925  2     1
2       12    0.902  2     1
12      15    1.0    2     1
16      21     0.91   1     2
18      26    0.98   1     2
26      37    0.88   1     2
16      21     0.925  2     2
18       26    0.902  2     2
26      37     1.0    2     2
....
```

I am having trouble figuring out a good automatic way to do this conversion/calculation in python though and could use some help on building a loop to iterate through this. Ultimately I have multiple datasets with anywhere from 3 to 100 markers and variable distances within those markers so it has to be adaptable to varying numbers and I'd like to use that input file with the markers and start/end data as a way to order it so that the output always has marker 1 first followed by marker 2 and so on (the variables here aren't always numerical so its just easy to give it a file specifying orders I think).

Thanks ahead of time for any suggestions.

**EDIT FOR MY SOLUTION**

I Believe I may have solved this after playing around with things (I think I was over thinking it). This is what I did where data.txt is the raw data set file and labels is the file describing the start end lengths:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv("data.txt")
df_labels= pd.read_csv("labels.txt")
order=list(df_labels.marker)
lengths=dict(zip(df_labels.marker,df_labels.end))
print(lengths)
count=0
df_edited=df_data.copy()
for l in order[1:]:
    df_edited.loc[df_edited.marker==l, 'start']+=(count+lengths[l-1])
    df_edited.loc[df_edited.marker==l,'end']+=(count+lengths[l-1])
    count+=lengths[l]
print(df_edited)
```

This led me to this output:

```
    start  end    time  group  marker
0       0    4  0.9100      1       1
1       2   12  0.9800      1       1
2      12   15  0.8800      1       1
3       0    4  0.9252      1       1
4       2   12  0.9022      1       1
5      12   15  1.0000      2       1
6      16   21  0.9100      1       2
7      18   26  0.9800      1       2
8      26   37  0.8800      1       2
9      16   21  0.9252      2       2
10     18   26  0.9022      2       2
11     26   37  1.0000      2       2
12     45   50  0.9100      1       3
13     47   55  0.9800      1       3
14     55   66  0.8800      1       3
15     45   50  0.9252      2       3
16     47   55  0.9022      2       3
17     55   66  1.0000      2       3
```

Which seems to be plotting correctly:

[image]

If anyone can think of anything more efficient let me know or if you have any thoughts on how to add a label on the plot indicating where marker 1 and and where marker 2 begins in addition to the x axis tick marks that'd be very helpful.